# BizTalk 2013 WSS Adapter Overwrite File

Tags: sharepoint, adapter, biztalk, wss

I am uploading documents through BizTalk 2013 WSS Adapter to a Sharepoint library.

In my WSS send port, I set this properties:

- Use Client OM: Yes
- Destination Folder URL: TempLibrary
- Overwrite: Yes
- Sharepoint Site URL: `http://testurl/`

The documents are being uploaded, but I receive anyway this error:

> A message sent to adapter "Windows SharePoint Services" on send port
>   "SPUploadDocument" with URI "`wss://testurl:80/TempLibrary`" is
>   suspended.   Error details: The Windows SharePoint Services adapter
>   failed to create a SharePoint file at the specified URL
>   `http://testurl/TempLibrary/Msg-bab31d9f-1d5c-4f70-9bcf-5908ad22fea9.xml`.
>   A file with this URL already exists and the overwrite setting of the
>   BizTalk Server port is not set to "Yes".
>
> This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive
>   location or send port with URI
>   wss://loppexdroomtest:80/TransitionLibrary.

How I can avoid get this error?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are being uploaded but you are still getting the error it might be related to this note on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560874.aspx) for the Overwrite property of a Send Port:

> Sending a large number of messages with the same name while the
>   Overwrite property is set to 'Yes' could result in SharePoint errors
>   being logged in the Event Viewer. These errors do not affect the
>   functionality of the adapter. Any message that fails will be retried.

But if that does not describe your situation you may want to check the Receive location settings. It sounds somewhat like your receive location has disabled Overwrite despite your send port *wanting* to Overwrite.

You may want to look at [Configure SharePoint Services Receive Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj684553.aspx) for the "Archive Overwrite" property. Or the "ConfigOverwrite" property as mentioned on this page [Windows SharePoint Services Adapter Properties Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547920.aspx)

Both of these default to "No"